# Java Sockets - Unexpected behaviour when using an IDE

Tags: java, sockets, ide

I have a simple test case :-

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",5956);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
        return;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Connected");
    }
}
```

When I run this from a command prompt then I get the expected output "IOException" when there is no server program listening on port 5956.

When I run this within my IDE, I get the output "Connected" even when there is no server program listening on 5956. I've tried this with Eclipse Helios and with Netbeans 7.0 RC2 that I only downloaded & installed a couple of hours ago - both give the behaviour described.

Any suggestions as to why and/or where to start looking for the reason for this would be gratefully received.

I'm running WinXP SP2, JDK 1.6.0_24

Regards

Comment: Presumably the IDE *is* actually running something on that particular port, for its own use. Have you tried running it from the command prompt while the IDE is running?

Comment: Displays "IOException" with or without the IDE running.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have killed the process listening on your server port. I just works as intended for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to check:
- what does netstat -ano |find "5956" report if no IDE is running? What does it report if the IDE is running?
- does your IDE use the same JDK version you are using from the command line?
- is your Windows firewall running? Did you perhaps add your IDE or the java executable to the allowed programs?

Comment: 1) netstat -ano | find "5956" returns nothing with or without the IDE running.

Comment: 2) As far as I can tell, they're both using the same JDK version.

Comment: 3) I'm using ESET rather than windows firewall with as far as I can tell the default set up. I amended the program to run through all the dynamic/private port numbers (49152 to 65535) and I con connect to 15,877 of then and only get 506 IOExceptions (all are blocked running from the command line) so there's definately something odd about the setup